# Holonomic planner for navigation

Tags: ros, navigation, planner, youbot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello !
I want to know how to have a holonomic planner for the navigation of a holonomic or omni-directional robot (KUKA Youbot for example).
The Idea is to be able to move the robot along the y axis without changing its orientation.
I tried to adjust the 'holonomic_robot' value of my planner (dwa planner) to true but the robot continue to not move as I want.

If someone can tell me how to configure my planner in order to do this, I will be very grateful.

lfr

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235250/holonomic-planner-for-navigation/) by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 201 on 2016-05-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can try the [eband local planner](http://wiki.ros.org/eband_local_planner) or the [teb_local_planner](http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner) .

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2016-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) on 2016-06-23**:
Yes, thanks, I tried the eband_local_planer planner and it works exactly as I want, thank you for your help (I forgot this topic ;) ).

**Comment by [dong_ym](https://answers.ros.org/users/31913/dong_ym/) on 2017-10-27**:
I follow your suggestions to use the eband_local_planner, and I use I default parameters as [http://wiki.ros.org/eband_local_planner].And I have a lot tests, and use rqt_reconfigure tool to config the related parameters, but the omnidirectional robots hardly translate in the y directions.